# XMl not being validated correctly against generated xsd

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I have the following xml

```
        <Payment xsi:type="ns4:PayCardDetails" xmlns:ns4="urn:main:types/common/payment_v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Card_number>354234</Card_number>
            <Card_type>xyz</Card_type>
            <Card_end end="2021-12-31"/>
            <Card_name>jacob K</Card_name>
            <Card_code>111</Card_code>
        </Payment>
```

xsd i created via tool :

```
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Payment">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Card_number" type="xs:unsignedLong" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Card_type" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Card_end">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="end" type="xs:date" use="optional" />
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Card_name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Card_code" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
```

I get an error when validating against the xsd of:

```
cannot resolve ns4:PayCardDetails toa  type definition Payment
```

I believe my xsd is not right, i recoved this xmlf rom third party and was trying to generate my own xsd. can i do that?

Comment: Your instance refers to xsi:type="ns4:PayCardDetails", and `ns4:PayCardDetails` must therefore be defined in the schema. It isn't defined in the fragment of the schema you've shown us, so unless it's defined in another part you haven't shown us, the error message is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @MichaelKay When you say define, how do you mean.  im defining the element

Comment: You're defining `Payment` in your XSD, true, but in your XML you're overriding that definition via `xsi:type="ns4:PayCardDetails"`, which as @MichaelKay says, is nowhere defined in anything you've shown.  If you don't intend to override the XSD's definition of `Payment`, then remove `xsi:type="ns4:PayCardDetails"`.